# REGEX to make string start from specific point

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have to split a string using regular expressions:
say `Nikolaus Kopernikus -> 1473-1543`

I tried the following, but it only gives me a list without `->`

What I need is the years 1473-1543, preferably in list `['1473','1543']`

```
import re

print ( re.split(r'->', 'Nikolaus Kopernikus -> 1473-1543'))
```

I want a regular Expression which makes the string start from a specific sign, thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a regular expression:

```
import re
re.match('.*->[^\d]*(\d+)-(\d+)','Nikolaus Kopernikus -> 1473-1543').groups()
#output: ('1473', '1543')
```

If you need a list instead of a tuple use the `list` function.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
'Nikolaus Kopernikus -> 1473-1543'.split('->')[1].strip().split('-') # ['1473', '1543']
```

From the docs:

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).

**Note**: I used [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove whitespace after splitting.

Comment: hmmm, thanks, but thats not done using Regular Expressions